# better way for url change using str_replace, not regular expressions

Tags: php, css, url, str-replace

I was changing css file urls like `str_replace('url(', 'url(somelocation/', $content);` 
now I want to exclude, absolute path ones, like url(/ does any one suggest something?

Comment: What's the problem with regular expressions?

Comment: I dont want to mess something that I can solve with a simple expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('@url\(([^/].*)\)$@', preg_quote($location) . '$1', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$location = 'somelocation'; // or however you're getting somelocation
if (strpos($location, '/') === 0) {
    $location = substr($location, 1);
}
str_replace('url(', 'url(' . $location, $content);
```